# echoing array results using 'While' does not show row 1

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops

I am using a 'While' loop to run through an array of users' first names, last names, and emails. When my 'While' loop executes, and I echo the data, it successfully shows the row data from the database, but it does not show Row 1. It starts at row 2 and spits everything out properly, but why is it skipping row 1?

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM email_list";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);


while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' : '
   . $row['email'] . '<br />';
   }

  mysqli_close($dbc);
```

One thing I have found, is if I put this section:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' : '
   . $row['email'] . '<br />';
```

above the 'While' loop, then it does successfully show the first row of data, and all the other rows too, so, if that's confusing, coding it like this (the long way - below) actually works, but it seems redundant and I want to use best DRY practices:

```
  $query= "SELECT * FROM email_list";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' : '
   . $row['email'] . '<br />';


while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' : '
   . $row['email'] . '<br />';
   }

  mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 calls to `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);` before you print your result. One before the loop and the other as the expression in the while statement.

Try deleting the one before the while loop.

```
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// kill this line $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' : '
   . $row['email'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify,
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
will pull the first row into $row then
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
is pulling another row before your loop's code is executed, so you dont need your first mysqli_fetch_array call.

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you very much, I thought I had to define $row outside of the While statement before using it IN the While.